# Facebook open graph og: and fb: tags are not working or being registered

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a website where I'd like to have a facebook like button, with the button being customized so it shows a specific picture, description, etc.

All of that is done and it works, however I used regular img, description, title meta tags instead of the og tags we are supposed to use.

Facebook complains when I lint the website with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

Here are some error messages:

```
Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property 
should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property
should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

and etc for all of the other tags...

Here is the problem: When I did add and configure the tags as shown in examples provided on the web, not only did it not work, I recieved another error:

```
Meta Tags In Body:  You have tags ouside of your . This is either because
your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally 
put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it 
before the tags are usable.
```

Here is my html config:

```
<html lang="en"  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

...

```
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="..." />
```

...

NOTE: My fb-root tag and the other fb provided like button code is at the very bottom of the page along with the other script's.

NOTE: I did zero configuration on open graph's website, or on facebook's open graph section of my app, in facebook developers, however I don't think that this is an issue because in fb's instructions, they said to add a like button only copying/pasting code is needed and no actual open graph configuration was needed.

Here is the site URL: http://darehut.com
NOTE: My tag code is actually inside the head element in my source, but for whatever reason, they get rendered outside!

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

> Meta Tags In Body:  You have tags ouside of your . This is either because
>   your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally 
>   put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place.

That message is missing the word `<head>` before the first period.

What it means, is pretty simple: Either you put your OG meta tags outside of your `<head>` element, or your HTML is malformed.

---

And next time you ask a question like this, please include the URL to the document you’re having trouble with – that way, we can have a look at it ourself and we’ll be able to answer more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you are right, my elements are not in the <head> element; but they are in my source html code. When the code is rendered, for whatever reason the meta tags (and a ton of other tags also) get displaced into a different tag called <body data-twttr-rendered="true"> Probably due to twitter bootstrap. But within that tag they are also inside the <div id="fb-root">. The URL of my site specifically is here: http://darehut.com The meta tags are all commented out at the very top, once again thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is the #fb-root element on top of your source code, outside of the html element …?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my actual local HTML source files, the fb root, along with the other fb script code is inside the <body> element, at the very very bottom of the page, and inside the <html> tag.

Comment: Well, in your online version it’s definitively not.